# Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) - Istio Gateway: How to configure the Application Gateway in front of the Istio Gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer, istio-gateway

I'm attempting to configure AKS, and I've installed **Istio Gateway,** which interns created an Azure Load Balancer, to make the overall traffic flow to be as shown below.

[image]

In my opinion, Azure Load Balancer is not required, **Istio Gateway** should connect directly to Azure Application Gateway, as shown below

[image]

Is this doable? If so, can I get any reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) : `Gateway describes a load balancer operating at the edge of the mesh [...]`, which means it's the point of entry (endpoint) to your mesh network. Even though it's virtual, it still needs some kind of underlying infrastructure (internal load balancer in your case) to host that load balancing service.

Now it's possible to configure your own ingress-gateway (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/), but it's usually much simpler (IMHO) to just use the one from your cloud provider, unless you have a specific use case.